# pandas: How to Series.sort_index() in-place?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to sort_index a pandas' Series in-place?

Well, of course, you can do this:

```
ser = ser.sort_index()
```

What I'm actually trying to do is to sort_index a Series-derived class, like this:

```
class SeriesAutoSorted(Series):

    def append(self, index, value):
        self[index] = value
        self.sort_index(inplace=True)
        # Won't work: No inplace option for Series
```

where `self = self.sort_index()` won't work either obviously.

Comment: What's the particular issue with `ser = ser.sort_index()`?

Comment: That cannot be applied in this case, because I'm trying to modify self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an undocumented `Series._update_inplace()` method that you could use. Pandas uses this [internally](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/69087192747ea670e1e781b25371f40ffec31073/pandas/core/series.py#L1784)

Here's an example:

```
In [50]: ser = pd.Series([5,6,7,5,4], index=[3,2,1,4,5])

In [51]: ser
Out[51]:
3    5
2    6
1    7
4    5
5    4
dtype: int64

In [52]: ser._update_inplace(ser.sort_index())

In [53]: ser
Out[53]:
1    7
2    6
3    5
4    5
5    4
dtype: int64
```